# How to limit an Apache server to only accept HTTP request from a city OR state in USA?

Tags: apache, security

How to limit an Apache server to only accept HTTP request from a city OR state in USA?

I have access to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: all the server or just one virtual server ? do you know the allowed ips list ? do you have access to iptables ?

Comment: One virtual server. I don't know nothing about "allowed ips list. How do you show it? I do have access to the ip tables.

Answer (score 0):

That information is not transmitted on an http header. Plus if it could the proxy would ruin all that info. This is how countries in general fail to keep certain traffic out. It's easier to establish which traffic is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install a GeoIP module such as [mod_geoip2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/).

Note that GeoIP data is not, in general, reliable—especially down to a fine-grained town level. If you choose to whitelist access based on city you will certainly block access to a significant number of people in the city, and all mobile users.

This is typically a really bad idea.